# Restart stopped container and execute CMD again

Tags: docker, cmd, podman

How do I make Docker (or `podman`, for that matter - interested in a solution for both or just one) re-run the `CMD` of a stopped container?

I've got this barebone `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM alpine
CMD ["date"]
```

I build it:

```sh
$ podman build -t reruncmd .
STEP 1: FROM alpine
STEP 2: CMD ["date"]
STEP 3: COMMIT reruncmd
--> 32ef88d23c0
Successfully tagged localhost/reruncmd:latest
32ef88d23c04eeb8b8bbafb1dc2851e9ce046fb88dbfddea020c16c3a1944461
```

Then I run it:

```sh
$ podman run --name re-run-cmd reruncmd
Fri Jun 18 06:20:33 UTC 2021
```

Now it's obviously stopped:

```sh
$ podman ps -a --filter 'name=^/?re-run-cmd$'
CONTAINER ID  IMAGE                      COMMAND  CREATED        STATUS                    PORTS   NAMES
2795e08162e1  localhost/reruncmd:latest  date     2 minutes ago  Exited (0) 2 minutes ago          re-run-cmd
```

But when I restart the container, the `CMD` isn't run again:

```sh
$ podman container restart re-run-cmd
2795e08162e1089eb639098a804ec7d8743ed274d4d7acbdc97f6b07ec1ecdfe
```

What do I need to change?

I used `podman` in my examples above; get the exact same behaviour with `docker`:

```sh
$ docker build -t reruncmd .
[+] Building 14.4s (6/6) FINISHED
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                        0.2s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 69B                                                                                                                                         0.2s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                           0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                             0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/alpine:latest                                                                                                           10.7s
 => [auth] library/alpine:pull token for registry-1.docker.io                                                                                                               0.0s
 => [1/1] FROM docker.io/library/alpine@sha256:234cb88d3020898631af0ccbbcca9a66ae7306ecd30c9720690858c1b007d2a0                                                             3.1s
 => => resolve docker.io/library/alpine@sha256:234cb88d3020898631af0ccbbcca9a66ae7306ecd30c9720690858c1b007d2a0                                                             0.0s
 => => sha256:234cb88d3020898631af0ccbbcca9a66ae7306ecd30c9720690858c1b007d2a0 1.64kB / 1.64kB                                                                              0.0s
 => => sha256:1775bebec23e1f3ce486989bfc9ff3c4e951690df84aa9f926497d82f2ffca9d 528B / 528B                                                                                  0.0s
 => => sha256:d4ff818577bc193b309b355b02ebc9220427090057b54a59e73b79bdfe139b83 1.47kB / 1.47kB                                                                              0.0s
 => => sha256:5843afab387455b37944e709ee8c78d7520df80f8d01cf7f861aae63beeddb6b 2.81MB / 2.81MB                                                                              1.0s
 => => extracting sha256:5843afab387455b37944e709ee8c78d7520df80f8d01cf7f861aae63beeddb6b                                                                                   1.9s
 => exporting to image                                                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => => exporting layers                                                                                                                                                     0.0s
 => => writing image sha256:c5faac680f09542b5efbfc9f9f9fe40265ea17e0654a47ac67040cf2f14473fc                                                                                0.0s
 => => naming to docker.io/library/reruncmd                                                                                                                                 0.0s

Use 'docker scan' to run Snyk tests against images to find vulnerabilities and learn how to fix them
$ docker run --name re-run-cmd reruncmd
Fri Jun 18 06:25:47 UTC 2021
$ docker ps -a --filter 'name=^/?re-run-cmd$'
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE      COMMAND   CREATED          STATUS                     PORTS     NAMES
0a3bfcc42814   reruncmd   "date"    11 seconds ago   Exited (0) 8 seconds ago             re-run-cmd
$ docker container restart re-run-cmd
re-run-cmd
$ docker container start re-run-cmd
re-run-cmd
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, `CMD` *is* executed at every start. You have been misled by the fact that `docker start` does not show you the result of `CMD`. If you run `docker start` with `-a` or `--attach` key, you will see the output.

```
❯ docker run --name test debian echo hi
hi

❯ docker start test   
test

❯ docker start -a test
hi

❯ docker logs test
hi
hi
hi
```

As you see from the last command, there were exactly three runs.

Comment: Thanks, this works. I indeed was just confused, because I didn't see output.